# jest: not found after npm install on Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, jestjs, azure-pipelines, npm-install, pipeline

### Problem

I'm running this pipeline file on Azure but I'm experiencing that a package is not found. I want to run tests using Jest with the command `npm test` after installing the packages with `npm install`. Jest is in the devDependencies in the package.json, I and think that's why it's not begin installed on azure.

```
sh: 1: jest: not found
```

**pipeline.yaml:**

```yaml
parameters:
  triggerType: ''

jobs:
- job: RunTests 
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  - script: |
      npm install -registry [[[[https://myregistryurl]]]]
    displayName: 'npm install'
  - script: npm test
    displayName: 'npm test'
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "ssu-dashboard-client",
  "version": "2.3.1",
  "description": "Dashboard for operation planning",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "Olavstoppen",
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --watch webpack.config.js --watch server.js",
    "dev:inspect": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --inspect server.js ",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.1",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-preset-jest": "^26.6.2",
    "color": "^3.1.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.4.0",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.12.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.0.10",
    "highcharts": "7.1.2",
    "highcharts-drilldown": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-more": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^2.2.2",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-google-charts": "^2.0.29",
    "react-highcharts": "^16.0.2",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.11.2",
    "react-measure": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.1",
    "react-saga": "^0.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "tinymce": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "adal-node": "^0.1.28",
    "applicationinsights": "^1.3.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-logger": "0.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-styled-components-config": "^0.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "helmet": "^3.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.7",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.3",
    "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.4",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
    },
    "verbose": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1",
      "^utils/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/utils/$1",
      "^locales(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/locales/$1",
      "^assets(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/assets/$1",
      "^styles/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/styles/$1"
    },
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./dist"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/tests/coverage/"
  }
}
```

My package.json is at the root of the project.

### What I have tried

I tried what was suggested underneath, but now I'm getting

```
npm install -registry [[[[https://myregistryurl]]]]
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[debug]which 'bash'
##[debug]found: '/bin/bash'
##[debug]which '/bin/bash'
##[debug]found: '/bin/bash'
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: --noprofile
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: --norc
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: /home/vsts/work/_temp/7aa1a129-08a3-43cb-8973-ce9f3c9748c4.sh
##[debug]exec tool: /bin/bash
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   --noprofile
##[debug]   --norc
##[debug]   /home/vsts/work/_temp/7aa1a129-08a3-43cb-8973-ce9f3c9748c4.sh
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/7aa1a129-08a3-43cb-8973-ce9f3c9748c4.sh
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2020-12-01T09_22_16_890Z-debug.log
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/bin/bash'
```

Could this be because the vmImages' being created are filling up the azure cache or something?

I tried adding `- script: npm cache clean --f` but this did not do anything.

### Update

It seems like the error is related to the registry, where I get a bunch of 401's

```
npm http fetch GET 401 ...
npm http fetch GET 401 ...
npm http fetch GET 401 ...
npm http fetch GET 401 ...
npm http fetch GET 401 ...
...
```

Comment: How about the result when you run the npm test in your local without Azure devops?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite 100% sure this is correct. But I'm suspecting the issue from the path execution file between locally vs azure pipeline.

Can you try as following by creating a script test on CI?

`package.json`

```sh
{
  "test:ci": "node_modules/.bin/jest"
}
```

Then you execute this command instead of local one:

```json
- script: npm run test:ci
```

Comment: Thanks, but still get an error... Updated the question :)

Comment: Can you collect the full stack trace?

Comment: A complete log of this run can be found in: `/home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2020-12-01T09_22_16_890Z-debug.log`. Where is this home dir? I tried downloading the logs from the pipeline run but that was not it.

Comment: You don’t need to see the complete one. Just the stack right where the message above was located

Comment: updated now, note that I took out the registry link.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like it’s failed before our scripts run. Can you update your yml file in the question reflecting what you have done so far?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225356/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-meerkat).